# Pytorch lightning, tensorboard: TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

this is my error. I don't know what's my error is. And I really do not know what to do right now. I am using PyTorch-lightning with tensorboard. I do not where this error comes from, I can provide more details if you ask. I delete several error information because StackOverflow doesn't allow me to post so much code.

```
  File "/home/jq/PycharmProjects/Unet/Code/Lit_train.py", line 49, in <module>
    trainer.fit(model)
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 859, in fit
    self.single_gpu_train(model)
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/distrib_parts.py", line 503, in single_gpu_train
    self.run_pretrain_routine(model)
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 1015, in run_pretrain_routine
    self.train()
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/training_loop.py", line 347, in train
    self.run_training_epoch()
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/training_loop.py", line 451, in run_training_epoch
    self.run_evaluation(test_mode=self.testing)
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/evaluation_loop.py", line 391, in run_evaluation
    self.log_metrics(log_metrics, {})
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/logging.py", line 74, in log_metrics
    self.logger.save()
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/utilities/distributed.py", line 10, in wrapped_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loggers/tensorboard.py", line 161, in save
    save_hparams_to_yaml(hparams_file, self.hparams)
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/saving.py", line 151, in save_hparams_to_yaml
    yaml.dump(hparams, fp)
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 290, in dump
    return dump_all([data], stream, Dumper=Dumper, **kwds)
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 278, in dump_all
    dumper.represent(data)
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/representer.py", line 27, in represent
    node = self.represent_data(data)
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/representer.py", line 48, in represent_data
    node = self.yaml_representers[data_types[0]](self, data)
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/representer.py", line 207, in represent_dict
    return self.represent_mapping('tag:yaml.org,2002:map', data)
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/representer.py", line 118, in represent_mapping
    node_value = self.represent_data(item_value)
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/representer.py", line 52, in represent_data
    node = self.yaml_multi_representers[data_type](self, data)
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/representer.py", line 343, in represent_object
    'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/object:'+function_name, state)
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/representer.py", line 118, in represent_mapping
    node_value = self.represent_data(item_value)
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/representer.py", line 52, in represent_data
    node = self.yaml_multi_representers[data_type](self, data)
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/representer.py", line 346, in represent_object
    return self.represent_sequence(tag+function_name, args)
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/representer.py", line 92, in represent_sequence
    node_item = self.represent_data(item)
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/representer.py", line 52, in represent_data
    node = self.yaml_multi_representers[data_type](self, data)
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/representer.py", line 343, in represent_object
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/representer.py", line 52, in represent_data
    node = self.yaml_multi_representers[data_type](self, data)
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/yaml/representer.py", line 317, in represent_object
    reduce = data.__reduce_ex__(2)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread.lock objects
Exception ignored in: <object repr() failed>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tqdm/std.py", line 1086, in __del__
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tqdm/std.py", line 1293, in close
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tqdm/std.py", line 1471, in display
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tqdm/std.py", line 1089, in __repr__
  File "/home/jq/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tqdm/std.py", line 1433, in format_dict
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Try to find out what's returned by `training_step` and `validation_step_end`. Is there something unusual?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have solved this problem.